# Custom unique constraint, only enforced if one column has a specific value

Tags: postgresql, database-design, index, constraint, unique-constraint

Is it possible to have a custom unique constraint as follows? Suppose I have two cols, `subset` and `type`, both strings (though the data types probably doesn't matter).

If `type` is 'true', then I want the combination of `type` and `subset` to be unique. Otherwise, there is no constraint. I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4 on Debian.

Comment: [MySQL users might find this kludge useful](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167546/18740)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In other words, you want values in the column `subset` to be unique among rows where the column `type` is 'true'.
A [partial unique index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html#INDEXES-PARTIAL-EX3) will do that:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbl_some_name_idx ON tbl (subset) WHERE type = 'true';
```

Data type *does* matter. If the column `type` is `boolean` (likely should be), you can simplify:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbl_some_name_idx ON tbl (subset) WHERE type;
```

This way you can even make combinations with `NULL` unique, which wasn't possible before Postgres 15. See:

- [PostgreSQL multi-column unique constraint and NULL values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9759/postgresql-multi-column-unique-constraint-and-null-values/9760#9760)

Comment: Thanks Erwin. I didn't see this option when I looked at the documentation. A more direct link is http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html. See Example 11-3.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I linked one level higher, since you need to *combine* a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) with a [unique index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-unique.html).

Comment: @Erwin That page (about partial indexes), has an example with partial unique index.

Comment: @ypercube: Ah, right. That's the better link. I changed my answer to point to that last chapter.

Answer (score 9):

This is supplemental to Erwin's answer above, but PostgreSQL supports a bunch of types of indexes.  These are not generally mutually exclusive.  You can think of these as being:

- Index method (btree, GiST, GIN, etc).  Choose one, if necessary (btree being the default)
- Partial or full.  If partial use a where clause
- Direct or functional.  You can index the output of functions.
- Unique or non-unique

These can all be combined in various ways. All you are doing here is using the unique and partial features, so that gives you partial unique indexes (which are extremely useful as you are finding out.

But suppose you want to have a *case insensitive* index on the subset field where type is true.  Then you would add a functional definition:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index_name_idx_u ON tbl (lower(subset)) WHERE type;
```

Note this creates a unique index on the *output* of the lower() function called on the subset attribute where type is true.

Comment: So the index in Erwin's answer is direct, whereas the one in your example in functional, correct?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Correct.