# How to create a unique index with only certain values required to be unique?

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I have a list of codes being stored in a table, and some codes should be unique, others can be repeated. The codes should be unique-scoped to another field, `product_id`.

Assuming the code `11` should only be allowed once per `product_id`, and other codes are allowed to repeat, the table would look like:

```
product_id     code
1              11   # Needs to be unique for product_id 1
1              222
1              222
1              333
2              11   # Needs to be unique for product_id 2
2              222
2              444
```

With MySQL, I took advantage of the fact that you can have multiple NULL values in a unique index, so by adding a "tie breaker"(?) field, `ucode` , I was able to hack together a solution:

```
product_id  code   ucode
1           11     1    # Code 11 needed to be unique, so 1 for ucode
1           222    NULL # Code 222 can be repeated, so NULL for ucode
1           222    NULL
1           333    NULL
2           11     1
2           222    NULL
2           444    NULL
```

Unique index was then made on [product_id, code, ucode].
For unique codes, the `ucode` field was set to `1`, otherwise `NULL`.

This works, but feels very kludgy. Is there a better way I can do this?

(I am using MySQL)

Answer (score 14):

In versions [MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) and [MariaDB 5.2+](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/) you can use a (generated) `VIRTUAL` column to accomplish this. You define`ucode` as a virtual column and then add a `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE codes 
  ( product_id  INT NOT NULL,
    code INT NOT NULL,
    ucode BIT AS (CASE WHEN code  = 11 THEN b'1' ELSE NULL END) 
        VIRTUAL,
        -- PERSISTENT,    -- for persistent storage of the value in MariaDB
        -- STORED,        -- for persistent storage of the value in MySQL 
    CONSTRAINT code_11_product_id_unique
        UNIQUE (ucode, product_id)
  ) ;
```

[Test at dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=576e927e52a1e82c64c061b90b8ac26f):

> ```
> insert into codes
>   (product_id, code)
> values 
>   (1, 11),
>   (1, 222),
>   (1, 222),
>   (1, 333),
>   (2, 11),
>   (2, 222),
>   (2, 222);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from codes;
> ```
>
> ```
> product_id | code | ucode
> ---------: | ---: | :----
>          1 |   11 | 1    
>          1 |  222 | null 
>          1 |  222 | null 
>          1 |  333 | null 
>          2 |   11 | 1    
>          2 |  222 | null 
>          2 |  222 | null
> ```

> ```
> insert into codes          -- should fail
>   (product_id, code)
> values 
>   (2, 11) ;
> ```
>
> ```
> Duplicate entry '\x01-2' for key 'code_11_product_id_unique'
> ```

> ```
> select * from codes;
> ```
>
> ```
> product_id | code | ucode
> ---------: | ---: | :----
>          1 |   11 | 1    
>          1 |  222 | null 
>          1 |  222 | null 
>          1 |  333 | null 
>          2 |   11 | 1    
>          2 |  222 | null 
>          2 |  222 | null
> ```

Comment: Oh my god, this should be the accepted answer for several dozen of "compound unique keys with NULL values" searches. Thank you so much!