# Avoid duplicated insert in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, insert, concurrency

I'm struggling to handle concurrent insert in my table on PostgreSQL.
I have the table `monitoring_services` with the following structure:

```
create table monitoring_services(
  id integer default nextval('seq'),
  user_id bigint not null,
  status varchar(25) default 'active',
  ...
)
```

And the possible status for a services are: `['active', 'completed', 'cancelled']`

Each user can have just one **active** service at a time.
When a user starts a service, a new record is created in the table with the default status "active".

For instance, this is posible:

```
user_id: 1, status: 'active'
user_id: 2, status: 'active'
user_id: 1, status: 'completed'
user_id: 1, status: 'completed'
```

But this isn't:

```
user_id: 1, status: 'active'
user_id: 2, status: 'active'
user_id: 1, status: 'active'
...
```

I created this index to avoid concurrent inserts and the user can't have more than one active service:

```
create unique index active_monitoring_service_idx on monitoring_services (user_id) where status = 'active';
```

I don't know if this is the right approach.

What would be the best way to handle it?
Thanks!

Comment: The partial unique index enforces your requirement, the approach is good. Do you need anything else? Or can we mark this as duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/37427/3684 ?

Comment: Hi Erwin! You're totally right, the other post is basically the same as mine! We can mark this as duplicated