# Creating a partial unique constraint for MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, constraint, null

I have the same question as asked in a previous post: [PostgreSQL multi-column unique constraint and NULL values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9759/postgresql-multi-column-unique-constraint-and-null-values%20PostgreSQL%20multi-column%20unique%20constraint%20and%20NULL%20values). But the solution there is not applicable as I am using MySQL instead of PostgreSQL.

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `col1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `col2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `col3` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I want the three columns `col1`, `col2` and `col3` to be unique. But a normal unique constraint

```
UNIQUE KEY `unique_constraint` (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`)
```

still allows me to insert identical rows whose `col3` is `NULL`. I want to forbid entries like these:

```
1  | 1 | 1 | NULL
2  | 1 | 1 | NULL
```

I was searching for a partial unique constraint in MySQL as proposed in the post above but apparently there are not supported in MySQL 5.5.

Can somebody give me a hint how to solve this best in mysql, I am also hoping there will be a performant solution!

Thanks from a newbie in mysql (coming from PostgreSQL)!

Comment: I guess you'll have to live with that limitation (or go back to Postgres)

Comment: Should `(1,1,NULL)` and `(1,1,5)` rows be allowed together or not?

Comment: @ypercube yes they should be allowed together.

Comment: Can't you make the columns `not null`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only option that comes to mind is a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. In 5.5 you could use `SIGNAL`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER bi_foo BEFORE INSERT on foo
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (ISNULL(NEW.col3) AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo 
     WHERE col1 = NEW.col1 AND col2 = NEW.col2 AND col3 IS NULL) > 0)
  THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
     SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot insert this item due to unique constraint', 
         MYSQL_ERRNO = 1001;
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[[sqlfiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6d8f/1)

But pre 5.5, you would do this something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER bi_foo BEFORE INSERT on foo
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (ISNULL(NEW.col3) AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo 
     WHERE col1 = NEW.col1 AND col2 = NEW.col2 AND col3 IS NULL) > 0)
  THEN
    SET NEW='Error: Cannot insert this item due to unique constraint';
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[[sqlfiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/525b2)