# Best database design for payments with multiple constraints

Tags: postgresql, database-design, constraint

I have to register payments.

- There are two things to pay. thingC or thingD (they may not be paid).
- You can only pay one thingD per payment transaction.
- You can pay many thingC per payment transaction.
- You can pay for thingC *or* thingD per payment, not both.
- There are three codes that have to be generated for each thingC or thingD that was paid.

***Existing tables***

**`thingC`**

```
idthingC serial PRIMARY KEY
--more columns
```

**`thingD`**

```
idthingD serial PRIMARY KEY
--more columns
```

***Tables I think I need:***

**`payment`**

```
idpayment serial PRIMARY KEY
idthingD integer REFERENCES thingD -- the payment may be for a thingD
type character(1) NOT NULL --C or D
c1 integer
c2 integer
c3 integer
```

**`payment_C`**

```
idpaymentC serial NOT NULL
idpayment integer NOT NULL REFERENCES payment
idthingC integer NOT NULL REFERENCES thingC
c1 integer NOT NULL
c2 integer NOT NULL
c3 integer NOT NULL
```

In table `payment` I'll have values in `idthingD`, `c1`, `c2` and `c3` if `type` is 'D'. The columns mentioned above will be null if `type` is 'C', and there will be values in table `payment_C`.

I have to be able to say:

- idpayment 1 was for thingD 2 and have the codes 1, 4, 8.
- idpayment 2 was for thingC 5 with codes 2, 3, 6 AND thingC 8 with codes 4, 5, 8

What do you think? In which table should the codes be? Can the design be improved.

Comment: Can the same payment be for 1 `thingD` *and* several `thingC`? Or are both mutually exclusive?

Comment: Only one thingD or several thingC per payment

Comment: I took the liberty to add this to the question - where defining info should go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously put some thought into this design. But you would regret that you have to search for codes in *two* tables. And what if you want to add details for codes?

I suggest to store all codes in the same table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE payment (
   idpayment serial PRIMARY KEY
   -- more payment details?
);

CREATE TABLE payment_code (
   idpayment_code serial PRIMARY KEY
 , idpayment      int NOT NULL REFERENCES payment
 , idthingC       int REFERENCES thingC  -- can be NULL
 , idthingD       int REFERENCES thingD  -- can be NULL
 , c1             int NOT NULL
 , c2             int NOT NULL
 , c3             int NOT NULL
 , CONSTRAINT either_c_or_d              -- reference either to c or to d
      CHECK (idthingC IS NULL AND idthingD IS NOT NULL
          OR idthingD IS NULL AND idthingC IS NOT NULL)
 , CONSTRAINT c_distinct_per_payment     -- distinct idthingC per payment (?)
      UNIQUE (idpayment, idthingC)
 );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_one_d_per_idpayment ON payment_code (idpayment)
WHERE idthingD IS NOT NULL;              -- only one idthingD per payment
```

*(Depending on the nature of the codes, maybe even just 1 code per row.)*

The partial unique index `idx_one_d_per_idpayment` disallows more than one reference to `thingD` per payment.

This allows at most 1 `thingD` per payment ***and*** any number of *distinct* `thingC`.

#### Mutually exclusive payment types

You later clarified, those are mutually exclusive.
This allows at most 1 `thingD` per payment ***or*** any number of *distinct* `thingC` (but not both):

```
CREATE TABLE payment (
   idpayment serial PRIMARY KEY
 , type_cd   "char" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'C'  -- optional default
   -- more payment details?
, CONSTRAINT type_cd_valid CHECK (type_cd = 'C' OR type_cd = 'D')
, CONSTRAINT redundant_uni_for_fk_constraint UNIQUE (idpayment, type_cd)
);

CREATE TABLE payment_code (
   idpayment_code serial PRIMARY KEY
 , idpayment      int NOT NULL      -- multicolumn ...
 , type_cd        "char" NOT NULL   -- ... FK reference
 , idthingC       int REFERENCES thingC
 , idthingD       int REFERENCES thingD
 , c1             int NOT NULL
 , c2             int NOT NULL
 , c3             int NOT NULL
 , CONSTRAINT either_c_or_d
      CHECK (type_cd = 'C' AND idthingC IS NOT NULL
          OR type_cd = 'D' AND idthingD IS NOT NULL)
 , CONSTRAINT c_distinct_per_payment
      UNIQUE (idpayment, idthingC)
 , CONSTRAINT payment_c_or_d
      FOREIGN KEY (idpayment, type_cd) REFERENCES payment(idpayment, type_cd)
 );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_one_d_per_idpayment ON payment_code (idpayment)
WHERE type_cd = 'D';  -- slightly simpler now
```

To enforce your rules, add a *type* column in table `payment` (I named it `type_cd` since "type" is too generic, and I chose [data type "char"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) - with double quotes - efficient for tiny enumerations). Include that column in the FK reference (redundantly). This allows a `CHECK` constraint (`either_c_or_d`) in table `payment_code` to enforce valid references.

The `UNIQUE` constraint `redundant_uni_for_fk_constraint` seems redundant, but is required for the [multicolumn FK reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) on `(idpayment, type_cd)`. Related, with more explanation:

- [Enforcing constraints "two tables away"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58970/enforcing-constraints-two-tables-away/58972#58972)

Both FK columns `(idpayment, type_cd)` must be `NOT NULL` to enforce referential integrity. Or (if you need rows without assigned payment) declare the FK constraint as `MATCH FULL`. Details:

- [Two-column foreign key constraint only when third column is NOT NULL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54387/two-column-foreign-key-constraint-only-when-third-column-is-not-null/54402#54402)
- [MATCH FULL vs MATCH SIMPLE in foreign key constraints](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58894/match-full-vs-match-simple-in-foreign-key-constraints/71508#71508)

Comment: The CONSTRAINT c_unique_per_payment should be for thingD

Comment: @KazMiller: This constraint is meant to disallow the *same* `thingC` more than once in the same payment. I added a `(?)` because I am not sure you need this constraint. You did not explicitly ask for it, but typically this would be nonsense. (There can still be multiple *distinct* `thingC` per payment.) I renamed it to `c_distinct_per_payment` now to clarify. The partial unique index `idx_one_d_per_idpayment` prevents more than one `thingD` per payment.