# Restrict two specific column values from existing at the same time

Tags: postgresql, database-design, constraint, postgresql-9.3, exclusion-constraint

I have a PostgreSQL example table where at most one row that is not of type 'c' should be allowed.

I would appreciate any help creating a constraint that will enforce this.

```
CREATE TABLE example
(
  example_id    serial PRIMARY KEY,
  example_state CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE example ADD CONSTRAINT 
  example_constraint
CHECK (example_state = 'a' OR example_state = 'b' OR example_state = 'c');
```

Comment: Your question is logically impossible. Once you have "all rows be of example_type 'c'" there are no other rows that can be 'a' of 'b'. Please clarify. Do you want to allow 0-n rows of type 'c' and only a single row with type in `('a', 'b')` - or 0-1 rows with 'b' and 0-1 rows with 'a'?

Comment: Corrected my wording.  Thanks for the answer; looks like the 'Singleton' answer was what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. And that's actually a very interesting question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### One row per rare type

If you want to allow 0-n rows with type 'c' and only 0-1 rows for type 'a' and 'b' (each), you can combine a simple `CHECK` constraint with a [**partial unique index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html):

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  example_id    serial PRIMARY KEY,
  example_state "char" NOT NULL CHECK (example_state IN ('a', 'b', 'c'))
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX example_unique_exception_idx ON example (example_state)
WHERE example_state <> 'c'; -- column is not null;
```

Related answer:

- [PostgreSQL multi-column unique constraint and NULL values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9759/postgresql-multi-column-unique-constraint-and-null-values/9760#9760)

An [exlusion constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) would be a related concept, but it won't work with multiple entries for `'c'`. You could use `NULL` instead of 'c' to make that work.

- [Preventing adjacent/overlapping entries with EXCLUDE in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504727/preventing-adjacent-overlapping-entries-with-exclude-in-postgresql/19505869#19505869)

Also note the [special data type `"char"`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) (in double-quotes!), which seems to be perfect for your simple purpose (unless it's just a simplification for the purpose of the question). It only occupies a single byte - as opposed to `char(1)`, which needs at least 2 bytes on disk and 5 in RAM.

#### Singleton row with any rare type

To restrict to a single row overall that does not have type 'c', use a partial unique [index **on an expression**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX example_single_exception_idx ON example ((example_state <> 'c'))
WHERE example_state <> 'c';
```