# Can column uniqueness be commutative?

Tags: postgresql, constraint, unique-constraint

I have a table in a Postgres DB where `col1` and `col2` are foreign keys referring to the same column. I want only unique combinations of `(col1, col2)`, i.e. if `(1,2)` is entered then `(2,1)` should be rejected. How can I achieve that?

My table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id serial primary key,
    col1 int NOT NULL,
    col2 int NOT NULL,
    unique (col1, col2)
)
```

Comment: [Prior question for the same on SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10159411/939860) Similar question [for three columns.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18361539/939860) For more columns you could have a [unique expression index on a sorted array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8443716/939860) or a `jsonb` value with a JSON array that is sorted internally automatically.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter 'permutations' was the keyword that I should have used. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This unicity constraint can be enforced with this unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idxname ON mytable(least(col1,col2),greatest(col1,col2));
```

Demo:

```
test=> insert into mytable (col1,col2) values(1,2);
INSERT 0 1
test=> insert into mytable (col1,col2) values(2,1);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idxname"
DETAIL:  Key ((LEAST(col1, col2)), (GREATEST(col1, col2)))=(1, 2) already exists.
```

Comment: Very smart, indeed.

Comment: I am constantly in awe of PostgreSQL - I'll be using it in future. This is a really nice answer and pretty cool! I thought that you'd have to jump through all sorts of hoops for this one! Am I right in thinking that not even Oracle has this capability? +1.

Comment: @Vérace: While I obviously agree with you on Postgres, Oracle also has ["function-based indexes"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5011.htm#i2078649). They have trouble with NULL values, though (which they did not implement properly): `Oracle Database will not use the index unless the query filters out nulls`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - how does PostgreSQL cope with NULLs in this scenario?

Comment: @Vérace: NULL values are indexed like any other value. Not relevant for this question since both columns are defined `NOT NULL`. More: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/9759/3684. If NULL was allowed for this special case, there would be more considerations since `GREATEST` and `LEAST` both prioritize non-null values over NULL  ...