# Composite index design where only a subset will be queried

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning

I have a table with columns `A` (type`date`), `B1` ... `B24` (all `boolean`).

Generally, `A` will always be used in every query and only one of `B1` ... `B24`. A large subset of the `B` columns (more than half) will generally be queried more than the rest, but all of them will be used fairly frequently.

Should I create indexes on 24 two-tuples of `(A, B1)` ... `(A, B24)`?
Or 1 huge composite index encompassing all the columns?

If I'm creating a lot of indexes, at what point am I adding too many indexes to the table and what is the approach to working that out? The table is used in a lot of core functionality and will be queried very frequently.

The `B` columns will only be filtered by `true`, and generally only one `B` column will be used in a single query. So the where clause of the query will generally look like:

```
... WHERE A = '2018-11-22' AND B12
```

Comment: Are you going to combine predicates on *multiple* B* columns in a *single* query or is it just `(A, B1)`, `(A, B13)`, etc.? But please disclose your version of Postgres first.

Comment: Generally only one B column will be used, e.g. `WHERE A = foo AND B1 = bar`

Comment: And am I right to assume the predicate will be `... AND B1 = true` (or simply `... AND B1`)? Meaning your queries will retrieve rows where the B*N* column is set (`true`)?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter correct!

Comment: Please [edit] to collect the whole information in your question for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider N **partial indexes**:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_a_b1_idx ON tbl (A) WHERE B1;
```

All together only occupying slightly more space than a plain btree index on `(A)`. You can have hundreds of indexes like that without problem. (I had a case with ~ 250.) The number is certainly not exhausted by the maximum of possible columns ([250 - 1600 depending on column types](https://www.postgresql.org/about/)).

Since each partial index is comparatively small, this will typically *benefit* performance as long as query patterns match.

Additional indexes may be useful and adding more index expressions may make sense to get index-only scans ....

Using a current version of Postgres is advisable in any case, but for this in particular, since there have been a number of optimizations for partial indexes lately.

To create all DDL statements:

```
SELECT format ('CREATE INDEX tbl_a_b%1$s_idx ON tbl(a) WHERE b%1$s;', g)
FROM generate_series(1, 24) g;
```

Returns:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_a_b1_idx ON tbl(a) WHERE b1;
CREATE INDEX tbl_a_b2_idx ON tbl(a) WHERE b2;
...
```

Related:

- [PostgreSQL multi-column unique constraint and NULL values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9759/postgresql-multi-column-unique-constraint-and-null-values/9760#9760)