# Constraint on multiple columns?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, index, constraint, graph

I have a table `edges`, which describes relations in a graph:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS edges (
   src INT NOT NULL REFERENCES nodes(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
  ,tgt INT NOT NULL REFERENCES nodes(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
  ,rel TEXT NOT NULL
  ,rel_type INT NOT NULL
  ,PRIMARY KEY (src, tgt, rel)
  ,UNIQUE (src, tgt, rel)
  );
```

After inserts:

```
select * from edges;
 src | tgt |    rel    | rel_type 
-----+-----+-----------+----------
   1 |   2 | 5.4.2.2   |        2
   2 |   3 | 5.3.1.9   |        2
   ...
   5 |   6 | 2.7.1.2   |        1
   5 |   6 | 2.7.1.147 |        1
   6 |   2 | 5.3.1.9   |        2
   6 |   3 | 5.3.1.9   |        2
   ...
```

I am using `rel_type` to specify edge directionality (`0`: undirected; `1`: source to target; `2`: bidirectional).

Hence, inserting `(3, 2, '5.3.1.9', 2)` is redundant with respect to the second entry above (for example) -- which already expresses the reciprocal relationship `2 --> 3` and `3 --> 2`.

How can I add a constraint that prevents the insertion of those redundant, reciprocal relations -- ideally `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`?

Basically, something like (these don't work: first due to syntax; second due to other issues):

```
ALTER TABLE edges ADD CONSTRAINT duplicate_rel_check CHECK ((src, tgt) <> (tgt, src) WHERE rel_type = 2);
```

or

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON edges ( greatest(src, tgt, rel_type=2), least(tgt, src, rel_type=2) );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `UNIQUE`, multicolumn, [partial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) expression index should do the trick:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON edges (LEAST(src, tgt), GREATEST(src, tgt), rel)
WHERE rel_type = 2;
```

Works with `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`.

Related:

- [Unique postgres constraint for permutations across multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18361539/939860)
- [How to create a postgres table with unique combined primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33705450/939860)
- [PostgreSQL multi-column unique constraint and NULL values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9759/postgresql-multi-column-unique-constraint-and-null-values/9760#9760)

Aside: If those are IP addresses, consider the data type [`cidr`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-CIDR) or [`ip4` from the additional module ip4r](https://github.com/RhodiumToad/ip4r) for column `rel`.

Comment: Awesome; thank you!  Re: `cidr`: these are biomolecular data (`5.4.2.2` etc. are enzyme codes, representing the edges: https://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?ec:5.4.2.2 ...).  I have another table (`nodes`), that specifies the source and target nodes, e.g. C00113, `d-glucose 1-phoshate`, https://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?C00103) ... https://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?org_name=hsadd&mapno=00010

Comment: @VictoriaStuart: I see. The sample just looked like IP addresses. :)

Comment: I nonetheless much appreciated the heads-up on that datatype. ;-)

Comment: @victoria: just curious - would those sorts of data not better be represented and queried as RDF triples ?

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind: yes; I am storing data in PostgreSQL, and constructing relational property graphs from those data.