# Constraint to prevent immediate loop in hierarchy

Tags: postgresql, database-design, unique-constraint, hierarchy, check-constraints

I have a `companies` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE companies (
 id bigserial,
 name varchar(255) NOT NULL
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I want companies to have parents and childs. A company might have many parent and many child companies, so I created the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE parent_companies (
 id bigserial,
 parent_company_id bigint,
   CONSTRAINT parent_companies_parent_company_id_fkey
   FOREIGN KEY (parent_company_id)
   REFERENCES companies(id),
 child_company_id bigint,
   CONSTRAINT parent_companies_child_company_id_fkey
   FOREIGN KEY (child_company_id)
   REFERENCES companies(id)
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I want parent and child to be unique, so I added the following constraint:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX parent_companies_parent_company_id_child_company_id_index ON parent_companies (parent_company_id, child_company_id)
```

This will not allow the same parent and child to be created twice in the database. However, I would like to also prevent a child company being saved as a parent of its parent company. For example, I would to prevent this from happening:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----+--------------------
id                | 1
parent_company_id | 1
child_company_id  | 2
-[ RECORD 2 ]-----+--------------------
id                | 2
parent_company_id | 2
child_company_id  | 1
```

Since in record 1 it's defined that company 1 is the parent of company 2, I want a way of preventing company 2 being recorded as parent of company 1.

I thought it could be the case of using the `EXCLUDE` or the `CHECK` constraints, but I couldn't figure out a way of making either work.

Comment: Do you want to allow cyclic paths with length > 2? Eg. (1, 2), (2,3), (3,1) ?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Oh, I hadn't thought of that case, but yeah I think it makes sense to not allow it if we're are not allowing the cyclic path with length 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is a many-to-many relationship between a table and itself (with additional restrictions). See:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9790225/939860)

Could be implemented like this:

```
CREATE TABLE company (
  id   integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, name text NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE hierarchy (
  parent_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES company
, child_id  integer NOT NULL REFERENCES company
, PRIMARY KEY (parent_id, child_id)
, CONSTRAINT no_1step_loop CHECK (child_id <> parent_id)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX hierarchy_no_2step_loop ON hierarchy (LEAST(child_id, parent_id), GREATEST(child_id, parent_id);
```

The unique index `hierarchy_no_2step_loop` rules out loops over two steps like you addressed in your question. Related:

- [Constraint on multiple columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/241075/constraint-on-multiple-columns/241079#241079)

The `CHECK` constraint `no_1step_loop` rules out loops over one step (rows referencing themselves directly).

**But** ruling out loops over more steps is not as simple. You could have a trigger follow the chain of links to the root and raise an exception if a loop is detected. That's more expensive and inherently unsafe against concurrent write operations, though. To make it bullet-proof, you'd have to operate with elevated transaction isolation (like [`SERIALIZABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE)) or write locks on all rows in the chain. But *that* is very susceptible to deadlocks under heavy write load ...

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do this with a single table and a self-referencing column?

```
CREATE TABLE companies (
   id         bigserial,
   name       varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   parent_id  bigint           NULL REFERENCES companies (id)

   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Then you can write some data:

```
INSERT INTO companies (name, parent_id)
VALUES ('Big Parent Company', NULL),
       ('Smaller Company', 1),
       ('Tokyo Subsidiary', 1),
       ('Zurich Subsidiary', 1),
       ('Zurich Manufacturer', 4),
       ('Zurich Distributor', 4),
       ('Another Big Company', NULL),
       ('Spanish Subsidiary', 7);
```

And you'll see that a subsidiary record can only have one parent record:

```
id  name                parent_id
--  --------------—---  --------- 
1   Big Parent Company       NULL
2   Smaller Company             1
3   Tokyo Subsidiary            1
4   Zurich Subsidiary           1
5   Zurich Manufacturer         4
6   Zurich Distributor          4
7   Another Big Company      NULL
8   Spanish Subsidiary          7
```

If every company needs to have a unique name (so that you don't have two subsidiaries with the same name), then another constraint can be added ... though this might create some unfortunate consequences elsewhere.

---

<sub>**Note:** Updated after a bit of clarification in the comments.</sub>

If a company can somehow have multiple parent organisations, then perhaps a second table could be used like this:

```
CREATE TABLE company_parent (
   company_id bigint       NOT NULL REFERENCES companies (id),
   parent_id  bigint       NOT NULL REFERENCES companies (id),

   ... { additional attributes } ...

   PRIMARY KEY (company_id, parent_id)
);
```

This would ensure uniqueness for any `company_id`+`parent_id` combination, but will not (by itself) ensure correctness of the data.

Of course, any company that does not have any record in the `company_parent` table could be considered the top-level organisation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Definitely appreciate alternative modeling suggestions like this. At some point I thought of doing it the way you described, and it seems like a good and somewhat standard way of approaching this problem (I've seen it somewhere before). Ideally, though, as I mentioned in the description, a company can have more than one parent, and it seems this way of modeling wouldn't allow that. Does that make sense?

Comment: needs `create unique index nodupes on companies( greatest(id,parent_id), least(id,parent_id));` to prevent  `update companies set parent_id = 2 where id=1; `

Answer (score 0):

So you want some kind of "anti-foreign key"?

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION chk_parent_companies(bigint) RETURNS boolean LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM parent_companies WHERE id = $1);
$$;

ALTER TABLE companies ADD CONSTRAINT chk_parent_companies CHECK(chk_parent_companies(id));
```

Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems this is checking the id of the parent_companies table? Not sure how that would be helpful. If company B is a child company A, we shouldn't allow the creation of a record that represents company B being the parent of company A. In other words, if there is a record in the parent_companies table with `parent_company_id: 1` and `child_company_id: 2`, I would like to prevent a record with `parent_company_id: 2` and `child_company_id: 1` from being created. Not sure how feasible that is. The cycle could be larger as ypercubeᵀᴹ mentioned.

Comment: Yes. Such constraint will prevent creation of company with the same id as already exists in `parent_companies`. So no company could be both "child" and "parent". If you need something more complex than I suppose you need to go for single and self-referencing column and more complex constraint function. Presumably something with recursive query. Need to think about it. I suggest you prepare a DB fiddle wtih samples of data